# Inserting and styling in external CSS on Notepad++ not responding

Tags: html, css

First time question. Was using a Udemy course to get the basics of html but hit a bump on the way to gaining an understanding. The html text has been jigged around with but to be quite unaware there is little to be found as to what is missing from the actual text. the main issue is not getting the border to appear and the text to align in the center.

```
 <pre><code><!DOCTYPE html>
     <html lang="en">
     <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <title>Picture Practice</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css_style.css">
    </head>

      <body>

      <h2 id=page-title>Picture Practice </h2>


    <div id="picture-container">




          </div>

    </body> 
    </html>

    /*#page-title{
       text-align:center;

         }

        #picture-container {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 400px;
       height: 400px;
       }/*****</pre></code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css file is correct, maybe the href on link tag references a wrong path. If your css file has been saved on a css folder, the indication href= css/style.css

Comment: when I try to add the '/' it denies the access. is there anyway i can work around this.

Comment: Also forgot to state this was built in Notepad ++